# Render Default Image, Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I defined an ImageField in my models.py, with a default image. Each time I create a new user, I can see in the admin that the default image is associated to the user, as I wanted.

The problem is, when I try to render it in my templates, with something like:

```
{{user.userprofile.profilpic.url}}
```

it does not work. The image is not displayed.

But if I go into my admin and change it manually, even with the exact same image, it works. It looks like the image is not saved into the db when I create the user.

Here is my models.py:

```
    class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User)
       profilpic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profilpics/", default="/my/picture.jpeg")
```

I wonder how I can fix that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method to your model:

```
class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
    ... 
    profilepic = ...

    def profilepic_or_default(self, default_path="/images/..."):
        if self.profilepic:
            return self.profilepic
        return default_path
```

and use it in your tempalte:

```
{{ myuser.profilepic_or_default }}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. But I realized my initial mistake was that I put the absolute path after "default=..", while it's supposed to be the path after "MEDIA_URL".

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [default templatefilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#default):

```
{% with default_image=STATIC_URL|add:"default_image.jpg" %}
     {{ user.userprofile.profilpic.url|default:default_image }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This is a really nice approach :)!

Comment: Sure, Tim's solution is there where it belongs to. But I like the creativity behind yours :)...

Comment: I never thought of doing it this way. I like it ;)